# pygtk.glade 'no module named glade' on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am using Python 2.7 on windows
I want to install a software called febrl on python which requires pygtk.glade
I have installed all the modules that were specified in the software manual, especially PYGTK all-in-one but i get an error when i try to import pygtk.glade (i have no error when i do : import pygtk)

```
import pygtk.glade
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named glade
```

Is there a way to install glade for python on windows? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Run this command below and it solve all your missing dependencies:

```
apt-get install python python-gtk2 python-glade2 libgtk2.0-dev libsqlite3-0
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to do `from pygtk import glade`

check this for more information:
http://www.pygtk.org/articles/pygtk-glade-gui/Creating_a_GUI_using_PyGTK_and_Glade.htm

Comment: Thank you @shi
however this command line does not work. I've already seen the link you posted but I am using Windows and not a Debian distribution

Comment: did you try import pygtk only if it imported then the problem is from the syntax @Manel

Comment: Yes as I said I have no error when i try to do 'import pygtk'

Answer (score -3):

By running `pip search glade` I get this

> BabelGladeExtractor (0.2dev-r288)  - Babel Glade XML files translatable strings extractor
>
> BD (0.0.5) - Bangladesh Details with postal code
>
> GladeBuilder (0.1.0) - Easy way to get and set values/properties of
>   Gtk2/Gtk3 widgets.
>
> SPE (0.8.3.c)  - Python IDE with Blender, Kiki, PyChecker, Remote debugger, Uml and wxGlade support

I am pretty sure doing either

```
pip install GladeBuilder
```

of

```
pip install SPE
```

will solve it. But then again you are on windows so it really depends.

Comment: Thank you but it still does not work... The installation of GladeBuilder was succesful however for SPE it says 'No matching distribution found for SPE
' and the import still doesn't work